# Throwing exception for wrong data types?

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, illegalargumentexception, throw

in the case that I want to throw an exception when the wrong type of data type is entered, how can I do this with IllegalArgumentException?

```
if(row < 1) {
        row = 1;
    }
    if(row > 5) {
        row = 5;
    }
    if (row != int) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter appropriate integer.");
    }
    System.out.print("Specify red value (0-255): ");
    int red = console.nextInt();
    if(red < 0) {
        red = 0;
    }
    if(red > 255) {
        red = 255;
    }
    if (red != int){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter appropriate integer.");
    }
    System.out.print("Specify green value (0-255): ");
    int green = console.nextInt();
    if(green < 0) {
        green = 0;
    } 
    if(green > 255) {
        green = 255;
    }
    if (green != int){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter appropriate integer.");
    }
    System.out.print("Specify blue value (0-255): ");
    int blue = console.nextInt();
    if(blue < 0) {
        blue = 0;
    }
    if(blue > 255) {
        blue = 255;
    } 
    if (green != int){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter appropriate integer.");
    }
```

My main problem is with the "!= int" part. I know for a fact that this is not right, but I am not sure what else to use. Using an else statement will not work either. If someone were to enter a double, string, or boolean input into the scanner instead of an integer, how could I throw an exception for this? I have to do this for an assignment, and they specifically said that I need to use a throw exception for this. Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: console.nextInt(), assuming console is of type java.uil.Scanner, reads an int (not a double, not a string, not a boolean), and it already throws an exception if the input is not an int. So, if you got a value in your int variable, you got an int and nothing else. An int variable will never, ever contain anything other than an int. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--

Answer (score 1):

```
(red != int)
```

**What are you trying to do**

Let me come to the question title **`"Throwing exception for wrong data types"`**. Well if this is the actual question then you dont need to do anything the line

```
int red = console.nextInt();
```

will automatically throw an exception if the data type is anything other than an **Integer**.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine but you might demonstrate catching the exception from nextInt()

Answer (score 0):

1. Making them new method for example.

   ```
   private void inputColorDetails(){
   if(row < 1) {
           row = 1;
       }
       if(row > 5) {
           row = 5;
       }
       if (row != int) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter appropriate integer.");
       }
       System.out.print("Specify red value (0-255): ");
       int red = console.nextInt();
       if(red < 0) {
           red = 0;
       }
       if(red > 255) {
           red = 255;
       }
       if (red != int){
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter appropriate integer.");
       }
       System.out.print("Specify green value (0-255): ");
       int green = console.nextInt();
       if(green < 0) {
           green = 0;
       } 
       if(green > 255) {
           green = 255;
       }
       if (green != int){
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter appropriate integer.");
       }
       System.out.print("Specify blue value (0-255): ");
       int blue = console.nextInt();
       if(blue < 0) {
           blue = 0;
       }
       if(blue > 255) {
           blue = 255;
       } 
       if (green != int){
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter appropriate integer.");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call them in main as try catch.

   ```
   private void Main(){
   try {
       inputColorDetails();
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       System.out.prinln(e.getMessage());
   }  }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You could look at using the "instanceof" keyword or  Class.isInstance()

```
var instanceof Integer
```

```
Integer.class.isInstance(var)
```

As JB Nizet noted, the nextInt() method only returns an integer though, so this check shouldn't be necessary.

To get any input and check it afterwards you could do

```
int color;
String input = console.next();
try {
    color = Integer.parseInt(input)
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input \"" + input + "\" was not an integer");
}
```

(Code off the top of my head, please correct me if I'm wrong)